# Exercise 1.5.5 in Guillemin and Pollack.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

The problem and its solution is given below:

> [image]

But I could not understand which proof the writer is taking about and how he get the third line in the proof. Could anyone explain this for me please?

And is there a mistake in the proof of the second part? or do we used that the derivative is merely the inclusion map?

**Edit:**

Here is another solution which I found:

> [image]

But I do not understand why $f\circ i$ is a diffeomorphism and why $T_{x}(W)$ is the preimage of $T_{f(x)}(Z)$, could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: Looks like the proposition at the end of Ch1.4

Comment: which page?@IAmNoOne

Comment: What about the third line in the proof?

Comment: It looks like to me the proposition describes the 3rd line.

Comment: which proposition there are two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Proposition:** Let $Z$ be the preimage of a regular value $y\in Y$ under the smooth map $f:X\to Y$. Then the kernel of the derivative
>   $df_x:T_x(X)\to T_y(Y)$ at any point $z\in Z$ is precisely the tangent
>   space to $Z$, $T_x(Z)$. (page 24)

Let $x\in W=f^{-1}(Z)$ and $f(x)\in Y$ and let $l$ be the codimension of $Z$ in $Y$. Then, by problem 4 on page 25, let $V\subset Y$ be an open subset of $Y$ around $f(x)$ and let $g:V\to\mathbb{R}^l$ ($g=(g_1,\dots,g_l)$ independent functions) so that $Z\cap V=g^{-1}(0)$. Then choose $U$ around $x$, open in $X$, so that $U\cap W=(g\circ f)^{-1}(0)$.

Then, by the **proposition**, $U\cap W$ is the preimage of a regular value $0\in\mathbb{R}^l$ under the smooth map $g\circ f$. Thus the kernel of the derivative $d(g\circ f)_x$ is precisely the tangent space to $U\cap W$, $T_x(W)$.

The third line in the solution that you found is simply unpacking what $\ker d(g\circ f)_x$ is.

Comment: did you see the other solution above ? I think it is much easier ...... what is your opinion of it?

Comment: I will put the image of the original question which state immediately that W is a submanifold ...... but could you please answer my question regarding to the second solution?

Comment: I could not understand the last 2 identities in the third line ..... could you explain them please?

Comment: Sorry the original question is included in the second picture

Comment: If $v$ is in the kernel of $(dg_{f(x)}\circ df_x)$ then we have that $dg_{f(x)}(df_x(v))=0$. Thus  $df_x(v)$ is in the kernel of $dg_{f(x)}$. And, certainly, you can reverse these.

Comment: Regarding your second question, I think the solution doesn't explain how $f\circ i$ is an isomorphism. They are not clear about that at all - personally I like the first solution.

Comment: yes it did not but is there any thing to say this? is f diffeomorphim?

Comment: The function $f$ is most certainly not a diffeomorphism here. There are a few sentences that require justifying that $f\circ i$ is a diffeomorphism. The domain matters here, it isn't true if we just have $f$.

Comment: Why is it most certainly not a diffeomorphism?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84870/discussion-between-prototank-and-idonotknow).